Screen stuck on grub after trying os-uninstaller, boot selection menu not appears with dual boot system
I have windows and ubuntu24.04 and tried ti remove windows os completely and for that used os-uninstaller, it choose windows and somewhere stuck whicl rewrite GRUB command and then I restart the computer and now grub screen comes
I am sure that windows partition might be corrupted but ubuntu is still safe and when try to check with ls

ls (hd0,gpt1)

output

efi/ System Volume information

so how can we edit grub so that it will start ubuntu .
Here is how all partition ls output looks like

Thanks
Update
After following some post I tried to set prefix but there is no boot folder so set
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/efi/boot/grub

and when run set
it gives below output

after that I do exit and windows starts but ubuntu is not working no boot menu appears at all

Here’s a summarized version of the main commands and steps to recover from a deleted OS situation using a live USB environment, including troubleshooting for common issues like disk space:
Prerequisites:

Bootable Ubuntu 24.04 live USB. ( although I has 23.10 USB while system installed was 24.04 but it worked)


1 Mount partitions

Boot into the live USB and open a terminal.

Identify the partitions:


sudo fdisk -l

You will see 2 partition, one is EFI ( sometimes it is not there ) and one is Linux FileSystem
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    239616 211358180 211118565 100.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 211359744 294244351  82884608  39.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 294246400 295315455   1069056   522M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 295315456 500115455 204800000  97.7G Linux filesystem



Mount the root partition (replace /dev/nvme0n1p6 with your actual root partition):

sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt


If there's an EFI partition (typically small, like 100MB):

sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi

2 Copy data from os_deleted to root
actually the os-uninstaller software moved files from root partition to os_deleted and hanged which is causing the boot issue
you can check whether /etc, /proc,  /sys, /run directories are under root partition (i.e.  /dev/nvme0n1p1 ) or not and if these directory are under os_deleted folder then we have to follow below steps.

If your data was moved to os_deleted:

sudo rsync -av /mnt/os_deleted/ /mnt/

This command copies the contents of os_deleted back to the root partition.
If "No space left on device" error occurs:
Remove large or unnecessary files:
sudo rm -rf /mnt/var/cache/apt/*
sudo rm -rf /mnt/var/log/*

Use find to locate large files:
sudo find /mnt -type f -size +100M

Then remove any unnecessary large files:
sudo rm /mnt/path/to/large/file

in my cae there are images and video files so removed those
3 chroot into the system

Bind the required directories:

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run


Enter the chroot environment:

sudo chroot /mnt

if above command gives error:

failed to run command  /bin/bash : No such file or directory  means you do not have all required files in root directory

you can run sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6 to check corrupted files
it chroot works succesfully your shell prompt will be changed to root@root
4 Reinstall GRUB

Install GRUB for UEFI systems:

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu


Update the GRUB configuration:

update-grub


If you encounter "unable to allocate pty", run

mount -t devpts none /dev/pts

5 Exit chroot and unmount

Exit chroot:

exit


Unmount the bound directories:

sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/run
sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi  # If mounted
sudo umount /mnt

6 Reboot

Reboot the system to check if GRUB is restored:

sudo reboot


Troubleshooting tips:
If "target is busy" during unmount, use:
sudo umount -l /mnt

To list processes using a mount point:
sudo lsof +D /mnt
sudo fuser -vm /mnt
sudo fuser -k /mnt  # To kill processes

Use rsync with --exclude to temporarily skip non-essential data if space is an issue:
sudo rsync -av --exclude='home/*' /mnt/os_deleted/ /mnt/
This should help for restoring the system and resolving common errors encountered during the process.
Hope it helps
